# Socket operation on non socket error in c using multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, udp

I am trying to achieve autonomous sending and receiving behaviour on the same socket using udp. The problem i am facing is that, once i finish off sending and wait for the second thread to continue receiving data from the server, it throws "socket operation on non-socket error". However i receive the first two packets successfully but then i receive some garbage and then this error comes. I have tried with static sockfd in case if the socket is not valid on the second thread for receiving but still the problem persists. Any help is appreciated.

```js
#include "client.h"

struct global_table{
  struct sockaddr_in *serveraddr;
  int sockID;
};

void *recvFromServer(struct global_table *rec){
  char recBuf[RECVBUFSIZE];
  int serverSize = sizeof(rec->serveraddr);
  // It successfully starts the thread and recieves the first two packets but then socket operation on non socket error comes. 
  while(1)
  {
    int n = recvfrom(rec->sockID, recBuf, RECVBUFSIZE, 0, &rec->serveraddr, &serverSize);
    if (n < 0)
      perror("ERROR in recvfrom");
    decryptData(recBuf);
    printf("Recieved: %s\n", recBuf);
  }

}

void pingServer(char *hostname, int portno)
{
  int sockfd; // Already Tried with static sockfd in case it gets destroyed if the main thread finsihes.
  int serverlen, n;
  static struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
  struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
  struct hostent *server;
  char *buf;

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) 
    perror("ERROR opening socket");

  server = gethostbyname(hostname);
  if (server == NULL) 
    perror("ERROR, no host found");

  bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  client_addr.sin_port = htons(5500);

  if (bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    perror("Socket could not be binded");

  if(setsockopt(sockfd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_TOS,&tos,sizeof(tos)))
    perror("Could not set socket option");

  pthread_t tid;
  static struct global_table server_info;
  server_info.sockID = sockfd;
  server_info.serveraddr = &serveraddr;

  pthread_create(&tid,NULL,recvFromServer, &server_info);

  serverlen = sizeof(serveraddr);

  while(1)
  {
    //Reads the entire file and sends it through udp packets. No problem in sending.
  }
  pthread_join(tid, NULL); // Once finishes sending, it should wait for the second thread to continue recieving data from the server.

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *hostname;
  int portno;
  if (argc != 3)
    perror("usage: <hostname> <port>\n");

  hostname = argv[1];
  portno = atoi(argv[2]);
  pingServer(hostname, portno);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'I have tried with static sockfd' why would you do that, (suicidal)?

Comment: To my understanding, the error comes in case socket is not valid. So making it static might be accessible on the second thread. However it was not a good approach as you mentioned it already.

Comment: What does the sending code do when it's finished sending? Is `decryptData` guaranteed to leave a valid C-style string in the buffer?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Yes it does leave a valid C-style string buffer. The problem persists even if i remove the decrypt function. The error remains the same.

Comment: What does the sending code do when it's finished sending? What does it do on an error?

Comment: Sending code(main thread) just waits for the second thread to recieve. At the moment it does nothing.

Comment: My best guess is that the sending code is somehow stomping on `rec->sockID`. Why not add logging of its value to your code and see if it changes right before you get the error?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, You are right, initially the value is 3, then it changes to 0 before throwing the error. Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: You need to figure out what code changes it to zero. Does some code explicitly do that? Or are you overwriting memory "randomly" and trashing it? It's almost certainly code you're not showing us, so it's hard for me to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143497/discussion-between-hassan-abbas-and-david-schwartz).

Answer (score 0):

The error you mention comes from using an invalid FD, for example a closed one.

However there are other problems here.

If `recv()` returns -1 it is not sufficient to merely print an error message and continue. You must close the socket and exit the read loop.

And you are completely ignoring  the case when it returns zero, meaning the peer has closed the connection, on which you must also close the socket and exit the read loop.

Similarly you can't just essentially ignore errors from `socket(), bind(), listen(), connect(), send(), ...`.

Comment: There is no peer to close the connection -- UDP is connectionless.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hmm, yes, missed that. Not in the tags. It would be more correct to say there is no connection to be closed.